# PyTables ptrepack cmd not accepting absolute path

Tags: python, cmd, hdf5, pytables

**Relative path:**

```
C:\Users>ptrepack JRC\git\metaTest.h5 JRC\git\cmdTest.h5
```

Produces the correct results

**Absolute path:**

```
C:\Users>ptrepack C:\Users\JRC\git\metaTest.h5 C:\Users\JRC\git\xxcmdTest.h5
```

Gives the Following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JRC\Anaconda3\Scripts\ptrepack-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(tables.scripts.ptrepack.main())
  File "C:\Users\JRC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tables\scripts\ptrepack.py", line 508, in main
    h5srcfile = open_file(srcfile, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\JRC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tables\file.py", line 318, in open_file
    return File(filename, mode, title, root_uep, filters, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JRC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tables\file.py", line 784, in _
_init__
    self._g_new(filename, mode, **params)
  File "tables\hdf5extension.pyx", line 370, in tables.hdf5extension.File._g_new
 (tables\hdf5extension.c:4321)
  File "C:\Users\JRC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tables\utils.py", line 157, in
check_file_access
    raise IOError("``%s`` does not exist" % (filename,))


IOError: ``C`` does not exist
```

Am I doing something wrong, it doesn't seem to be interpreting the C as a drive letter.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue on github https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/616
I also met this problem, i used workaround - to add ":" to end of path, for example:
C:\Users>ptrepack C:\Users\JRC\git\metaTest.h5: C:\Users\JRC\git\xxcmdTest.h5: